# Filter features with properties in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

I'd like to filter features on the map using the feature properties.

For example if I have this property in the geojson:

```
...
"properties": {
                "Start": 10
            }
...
```

And I want to see only featuers with `Start > 10`, how can I implement that features with `Start < 10` are hidden?

If I change the style with following code the features are transparent but they are still available after click if I use `forEachFeatureAtPixel`. I want that features are not displayed and there are not available for clicking etc.

```
let invisibleStyle = new ol.style.Fill({
    color: [0,0, 0, 0],
});

const NewLayer= new ol.layer.VectorImage ({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            url: *url*,
            format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        }),
        visible: true,
        style: function (feature) {
        if (feature.get('Start')>10) {
            let style = new ol.style.Style({
                fill: fillStyle,
                stroke: strokeStyle
            })
            return style;   
        } else {
            let style = new ol.style.Style({
                fill: invisibleStyle,
            })
            return style;   
        }   
    });
map.addLayer(NewLayer);
```

I tried also to use the `visible` like this but it doesn't work:

```
const NewLayer= new ol.layer.VectorImage ({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            url: *url*,
            format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        }),
        visible: function(feature) {
                 if (feature.get('Start')<10) {
                    return true;
                 } else {
                    return false;
                 }
          },
        style: new ol.style.Style({
              fill: fillStyle,
              stroke: strokeStyle,
              })      
    });
map.addLayer(NewLayer);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transparent fill cannot be seen but is hit detected (so you can select a polygon by clicking inside it).  To avoid display and hit detection simply don't return a style

```
    style: function (feature) {
      if (feature.get('Start')>10) {
        let style = new ol.style.Style({
            fill: fillStyle,
            stroke: strokeStyle
        })
        return style;   
      }
    }
```